# show result into html table from database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i have textfield inside html table..i want after i type something like "name" in another cell can show all information or description about people who have that name...that information are take from "member_table"...

```
<tr>
  <td>
      <td>
         <td><input type="text"........></td>
      </td>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td> //i want information show here
   </td>
<tr>
```

what's code for it?

Comment: Lots.  Probably more than you've given us in your question. Show us the HTML for your member_table and other relevant information from your markup.

Comment: You need to use jQuery to get data from DB when user finish writing in the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer would be in 3 part.

```
<tr>
   <td> //i want information show here
   </td>
<tr>
```

modify this to

```
<tr>
   <td> <div id="divResult"></div></td>
<tr>
```

Now you need to write javascript

```
<script>
 // Get the data from the text field
var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName").value;

// Assuming there is a Ajax Function
ajax(txtName);
//Call back function for ajax
function callBack()
{
  if(ajaxObj.... )
  {
    document.getElementById("divResult").innerHTML = ajaxObj.responseText;
  }
}

</script>
```

The third part is getting the required data from Mysql server from PHP.

```
<?php

$name = $_REQUEST['txtName'];
echo getDataFromMySQL($name);
?>
```